# Unable to share post on Facebook. Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP response code

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

Every meta tag and scripts are on point.

```
<head>
 <title>@ViewData["Title"]-***</title>
 <meta property="og:url" content="@ViewData["Url"]#" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="@ViewData["Heading"]" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="@ViewData["Description"]" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="@ViewData["Image"]#" />
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="***" />
</head>
```

on facebook debugger getting this warning:
Bad Response Code
URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
Response Code   404

Comment: What URL are you trying to share? And if Facebook share debugger say that you return 404 it means that you return 404

Comment: I am trying to share https://tajforhomes.com/Blog/BlogDetail/1#. I dont understand I return 404. I am newbie in this so its little confusing for me.

Comment: I would start removing the # character and see if that helps.

Comment: Plus you got your `og:url` set to `/Blogs/...`, plural.

Comment: does it really make difference? singular plural? @CBroe

Comment: I have tried it also but it didn't work.

Comment: Whether it makes a difference, depends solely on how _your_ system handles these two different URLs.